# mysql update without replacing existing data

Tags: mysql

I need to update a row in my  mysql database, but i don't want to replace the data that is already stored in it. example:

```
select books from storedb where id='Rick';
```

result of the query: Books = "example1"

but i need to update that row and add more books.

```
update storedb set books='example2' where id='Rick';
```

but it replaces the current data, so i need to do it without replacing current data.
somethink like this: books='example1 -- example2";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you need a string concatenation?
Try this:

```
update storedb set books=CONCAT(books,' -- ', 'example2') where id='Rick';
```